# Doing something at the very end of recursive quickSort

Tags: java, quicksort

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int begin, int end, String s) {

    int i = begin, j = end;

    int middle = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
    int pivot = a[middle];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (a[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
            quickSortComparisons++;
        }

        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
            quickSortComparisons++;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            quickSortExchanges++;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    // recursively sort two sub parts
    if (begin < j)
        quickSort(a, begin, j, s);

    if (end > i)
        quickSort(a, i, end, s);

    quickSortWork = quickSortComparisons + (3 * quickSortExchanges);

    // WANT TO DO SOMETHING HERE WHEN THE ARRAY 
    //IS COMPLETELY SORTED AND ALL RECURSIVE CALLS ARE FINISHED.
}
```

I'm trying to implement a quickSort function. It sorts correctly, but the issue I'm having is that I need to print some things when the array is completely sorted. since this is called recursively, if I just print at the end, it gets printed every single time the function is called. Is there some type of dummy base case I can create, perhaps something like:

```
if(!sorted){ //do all quicksort operations}
else{ //print values I wish to print}
```

Comment: Just create a new function that (1) calls your existing function, and (2) prints whatever values you want.

Comment: that doesn't help, it will just be called over and over again. I essentially want to perform some action once the quickSort is completely finished, not when each individual iteration is complete.

Comment: Then you misunderstand what I mean. Your existing `quickSort` function would continue to call itself recursively. Your new function would call `quickSort` and then print whatever values. Don't try to put the printing part inside the recursive function.

Comment: ahhh, understood. I ended up creating a sorted() function that returns a boolean value and this worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the initial call in a non-recursive function like this:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int begin, int end, String s) {
    // Call the recursive method
    quickSort0(a, begin, end, s);

    // When you get here, the array is sorted
    System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(a));
}

private static void quickSort0(int[] a, int begin, int end, String s) {
    // Your original, recursive quickSort method
}
```

Comment: within quickSort0 would i recursively call quickSort or quickSort0? I'm assuming the latter.

Comment: Correct, you'd call `quickSort0`